# C++ brace initializer list, temporary lifetime

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, temporary-objects

I've got following code:

```
string join(initializer_list<string_view> strings);
```

initializer_list is std::initializer_list and string_view isn't std::string view but very similar class with constructors from const string& and const char*.

Then I've got following invocation of `join`:

```
EXPECT_EQ("this", join({ string("this") }));
```

After small investigation I've found that the first element of resulting initializer list isn't `"this"` but `"\0his"`. This is becouse the destructor of the temporary created by `string("this")` is called right after creation of temporary `string_view` (so it contains invalid pointers). Why is it so that the lifetime of `string("this")` isn't extended to the end of the full-expression `EXPECT_EQ("this", join({ string("this") }));`?

## Edit

Ok, as you suggested there is self-contained example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class string_view {
public:
    string_view(const string& str)
        : _begin(str.data())
        , _end(str.data() + str.size()) {
    std::cout << "string_view(...)" << std::endl;
    }

    const char* _begin;
    const char* _end;
};

void join(initializer_list<string_view> strings) {
    std::cout << "join(...)" << std::endl;
    for (auto i = 0u; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << int(strings.begin()->_begin[i]) << " " << strings.begin()->_begin[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    join({ string("this") });
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this program compiled with last Visual Studio C++ (Express):

```
string_view(...)
join(...)
0
104 h
105 i
115 s
0
```

It may vary from compiler to compiler as above program is probably ill-formed.

I've investigated what is the order of calls in debugger, and there is the sequence:

```
main()
    basic_string(const char*)
    string_view(const string&)
    ~basic_string()
    initializer_list(...)
    join(...)
```

I would like the content of the `string("this")` to be available inside `join` function. And it is not the case, becouse `string("this") is destroyed before.

Why is the destructor of temporary string `string("this")` invoked before the `join` function is called or in other words why isn't the lifetime of `string("this")` extended to the end of the full-expression `join({ string("this") })`?

Comment: please give a self-contained example of your code, not just a single line

Comment: I don't understand why you would take an `initializer_list` argument and not some container type that you can initialise with a list.

Comment: If `EXPECT_EQ` is a macro, then it's impossible to tell whether there's a "full-expression" at al. That said, the string view only needs to live for the duration of the `join` call, which it patently does, so I suspect that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: For reference, the lifetime of initializer list objects and their elements is described in 8.5.4/5-6.

Comment: Joseph: If I understood you correctly, the one of reasons I am using initializer_list instead of for example vector is I want to avoid copying of elements.

Comment: Hmm. VS is known to have bugs related to `initializer_list`. The temporary `string("this")` should live long enough to make this program well-behaved.

Comment: Wrt the order of construction/destruction, this really looks like a VS bug.

Comment: [This is what I would expect](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c5d9b88bc4025e4)

Comment: I didnt write it before, but I've started experiencing issue after reinstalling my system and Visual Studio (with Update 2), before it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What I think *might* be happening here is that you are constructing your initializer_list from a reference to your string, so that the string goes out of scope when your initializer_list has finished constructing.

You see your string is not a parameter to the join() function but to the initializer_list you construct.

My guess is that the initializer_list is constructed, your string goes out of scope and then your join() function tries to access the dead string through the reference contained in the string_view.

Comment: Temporaries live at least until the end of the full-expression in which they've been created.

Comment: Yes, this is what probably happens here but by dyp's notice it shouldn't.

Comment: @dyp Yes, but, but that expr here for the tmp string is the actual arg of the init-list's **member's** ctors, not the tmp init-list itself.

Comment: @Solkar I don't quite understand what you mean. `join({ string("..") });` is a full-expression, and `string("..")` is a sub-expression creating a temporary. The `{ ..}` creates a temporary `std::initializer_list<string_view>`. Both temporaries will (should) be destroyed at the end of the full-expression.

Comment: @dyp I understand that this rule  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization "a temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor initializer list persists only until the constructor exits, not as long as the object exists". takes precedence here.

Comment: @Solkar The temporary is not created in the constructor's member-initializer-list, but due to list-initialization of the function parameter of the constructor.

Comment: The ctor called for "join()"'s actual arg is a default like in `std::list_initializer<string_view> string{std::list_initializer<std::string>&&}`, isn't it.

Comment: std::list_initializer<string_view> strings{std::list_initializer<std::string>&&} that is.

Comment: @Solkar If you don't add `@dyp` to your comments, I won't receive a notification. -- For the call to `join(..)`, the `{..}` creates a temporary `std::initializer_list` and moves that prvalue to the function parameter. The temporary is therefore not created *inside the mem-initializer-list*. The *mem-initializer-list* is the part *after* the `:` in a constructor. For example, `struct foo{string&& s; foo():s("hello")};` This creates a dangling reference, since `"hello"` is converted to a `string`, and this conversion creates a temporary *inside the mem-initializer-list*.

Comment: @dyp: I'm aware what a *mem-initializer-list* is. Above quote is not about *creation in* but *binding to*.

Comment: @Solkar Ah, I see. Hmm. I looked this up in the Standard, and it seems to be an unfortunate formulation: "A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* persists until the constructor exits." [class.temporary]/5 As far as I can tell, this should refer to the temporary as a prvalue, not as an object potentially hidden behind a reference/pointer. Imagine the ctor was defined in another TU, where we don't have any information about the lifetime of the arguments.

Comment: @dyp Your point has its merits; it could indeed become a very tedious task trying to anticipate what state the compiler creates if my hypothesis would hold. What most keeps me ponder is that we here have a aggregate<T1> used to ctor aggregate<T2>, it's not just T2(whatever_extend<T1>::type t1) we're dealing with here.