# Concatenate a family of string

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

I would like to write a function that concatenates any sequence of `std::string` with just *one malloc* behind the scene. As a consequence, the total length of the string needs to be computed first. The function needs to be used that way:

```
std::string s0 = ...;
std::string s1 = ...;
std::string s2 = ...;

std::string s = join(s0, s1, s2);
```

A better `join` would use a mix of `std::string` and `std::string_view`. It would be even better if we could add string literals. How would you write such a function in C++11 (it needs to compile with `gcc 4.8.5` and `Visual Studio 2015`)?

Comment: How about [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)? Sure it's not a single allocation, but if you want variable number of arguments it's not going to be possible. If you have a fixed number of arguments it's possible though. Can you perhaps please elaborate on that requirement, of having only a single allocation?

Comment: I don't understand the close vote:  This isn't asking for an offsite resource - it is asking for code to solve a problem. I think it's a poor question though ...

Comment: @Martin: Why is it poor?

Comment: @Some: I need a variable number of arguments and a single allocation

Comment: You can't use `std::string_view` in C++11 - it is introduced by C++17.  You have two problems:  writing a function that accepts an arbitrary list of `std::string` or `const char*` without causing allocations, and iterating over such a list to create the output string.

Comment: Get the `c_str` behind the scene, allocate, copy and built the string over it.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry. It turns out that I have my own `string_view` that I use in `C++11`. I just did not want to bother with my class.

Comment: It is poor because you haven't shown what you have tried, and it sounds like homework (or you haven't explained why it is important to have only *one* allocation).

Comment: @Martin. I undesrtand. I have tried and so far, the only solution I have implies many overloads for all combinations for 2,3,4 number of strings. For single allocation, I need performance. A malloc is easily `30 ns` while a string copy of a few characters is about `2 ns`.

Comment: Performance is the *last* thing you should worry about when programming. First and foremost make sure you have something which is readable, maintainable and *works*. Then, and only if the "performance" is not "good enough" (which most of the time really *is* good enough) you measure and profile and benchmark to find the hotspots and bottlenecks, and concentrate on the worst of those (remembering to document all optimizations you do, with plenty of comments). Then start over with testing and measuring and optimizations until it is good enough.

Comment: @Some: I do care about performance because this is my job. But I am more of a C programmer than a C++ programmer. Which is why I am not as familiar with parameters unpacking and things like that.

Comment: It might actually be possible to do with only a single allocation, followed by multiple copies, but it requires two passes over the arguments: One to accumulate the total size, and one to do the copying. Will it be faster than simply adding to an `ostringstream`? I don't know. But I suggest you start reading up on parameter packs, or variable template arguments which is going to be needed in any case.

Comment: @Some: Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: That is unavoidable. The single allocation must include the size of the last argument, but the allocation must also precede the copy of the first argument. That allocation therefore separates first pass and second pass.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `string_view` type, then you can just accept a collection of `string_view`s, sum their sizes, allocate, then copy in.

```
std::string join(std::initializer_list<string_view> values)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0, [](string_view s) { return s.length(); }));
    std::for_each(values.begin(), values.end(), [&result](string_view s) { result.append(s.data()); });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That's what `string_view::string_view(const std::string &)` etc are for. [minor caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586411/c-brace-initializer-list-temporary-lifetime): don't construct temporary `std::strings` in the argument to `join`

Answer (score 3):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you might use `concat`:

```
const std::string s = ranges::view::concat(s0, s1, " world\n");
```

Comment: Nice to know. I'll check the implementation

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible implementation:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::string join(const Args&... args)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    for( const std::string& s : { args... } )
        size += s.size();

    std::string result;
    result.reserve(size);
    for( const std::string& s : { args... } )
        result += s;
    return result;
}
```

Demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/qwG0LMewsHwVuGXN

Comment: Note that requires that all `args` are of the same type (and convertible to `std::string`), you cannot mix `std::string` and C literal string.

Answer (score 2):

Benoit almost had it, his implementation just needed the necessary boiler-plate to handle different string types.  To his credit, I must admit that it is quite a bit of boiler-plate. :)

Compiles with `gcc -std=c++17`

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail {

    template<typename C> 
    size_t myStrLen(const std::basic_string<C>& s) { return s.length(); }

    template<typename C> 
    size_t myStrLen(const std::basic_string_view<C>& s) { return s.length(); }

    size_t myStrLen(char)    { return 1; }
    size_t myStrLen(wchar_t) { return 1; }

    size_t myStrLen(const char* s) { return strlen(s); }
    size_t myStrLen(const wchar_t* s) { return wcslen(s); }

    template<typename T, typename...Args>
    size_t myStrLen(T&& t, Args&&...args)
    {
        return myStrLen(std::forward<T>(t)) + myStrLen(args...);
    }

    template<typename C, typename T>
    void myConcat(std::basic_string<C>& result, T&& t)
    {
        result += t;
    }

    template<typename C, typename T, typename...Args>
    void myConcat(std::basic_string<C>& result, T&& t, Args&&...args)
    {
        result += t;
        myConcat(result, args...);
    }

}

template<typename C, typename... Args>
auto join(Args&&... args)
{
    std::basic_string<C> result;
    result.reserve(detail::myStrLen(args...));
    detail::myConcat(result, args...);
    return result;
}

template<typename... Args>
auto join(Args&&... args)
{
    return join<char>(args...);
}

template<typename... Args>
auto wjoin(Args&&... args)
{
    return join<wchar_t>(args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::string str{"hello"};
    std::string_view sv{"world"};

    std::wstring wstr{L"hello"};
    std::wstring_view wsv{L"world"};


    std::cout << join(str, " ", sv, '\n');
    std::wcout << wjoin(wstr, L" ", wsv, L'\n');

    return 0;
}
```

[EDIT] Moved template `join<charType>` out of namespace detail, since that can be useful for other template constructs.

Comment: In C++17, you may even do `template<typename...Args>
    std::size_t myStrLen(Args&&...args)
    {
        return (myStrLen(std::forward<Args>(args)) + ...);
    }`

Comment: Yes, but MS doesn't support it yet,. :(  So I don't have the reflex yet ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is possible using perfect forwarding and variadic template argument.

joinStr.hpp :

```
    class joinStr {
    public:
        template<typename... Args>
            joinStr(const std::string& first, Args&&... args): ret(""), size(0) {
                size = first.length();
                getSize((args)...);
                std::cout << "before reserve : " << ret.capacity() << std::endl;
                ret.reserve(size);
                std::cout << "after reserve : " << ret.capacity() << std::endl;
                ret.append(first);
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        ~joinStr() {}
        std::string getStr() {
            std::cout << ret << std::endl;
            return ret;
        }
    private:
        std::string ret;
        int size;
        int getSize() {
            std::cout << "size : " << size << std::endl;
            return size;
        }
        template<typename... Args>
            int getSize(const std::string& first, const Args&... args) {
                size += first.length();
                return getSize((args)...);
            }
        template<typename... Args>
            int getSize(char* first, const Args&... args) {
                size += strlen(first);
                return getSize((args)...);
            }
        template<typename... Args>
            int getSize(const char* first, const Args&... args) {
                size += strlen(first);
                return getSize((args)...);
            }
        void join() {
            std::cout << "Final capacity : " << ret.capacity() << std::endl;
        }
        template<typename... Args>
            void join(const std::string& first, Args&&... args) {
                ret.append(first);
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        template<typename... Args>
            void join(char* first, Args&&... args) {
                ret.append(first);
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        template<typename... Args>
            void join(const char* first, Args&&... args) {
                ret.append(first);
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
};
```

main :

```
int main() {
    std::string s1 = "hello";
    std::string s2 = "world !";
    std::string s3 = "meatpopsicle";
    const char* s4 = "__yeah__";
    joinStr c(s1, s2, s3, s4);
    return 1;
}
```

Note that I wrapped it inside a class but you could do the same outside a class.

As a bonus, it works both with std::string, const char* and char*.

**Edit** : fixed re-using moved values in getSize and added template for const char* after [Caleth's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610810/caleth) suggestion

**Edit 2** : 
Version that allows to pass a size_t field after a const char* instead of using strlen.

```
 class joinStr {
    public:
        template<typename... Args>
            joinStr(const std::string& first, Args&&... args): ret(""), size(0) {
                size = first.length();
                getSize(args...);
                std::cout << "before reserve : " << ret.capacity() << std::endl;
                ret.reserve(size);
                std::cout << "after reserve : " << ret.capacity() << std::endl;
                ret.append(first);
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        ~joinStr() {}
        std::string getStr() {
            std::cout << ret << std::endl;
            return ret;
        }
    private:
        std::string ret;
        int size;
        int getSize() {
            std::cout << "size : " << size << std::endl;
            return size;
        }
        template<typename... Args>
            int getSize(const std::string& first, const Args&... args) {
                size += first.length();
                return getSize((args)...);
            }
        // const char *
        template<typename... Args, typename T>
            int getSize(const char* first, const T& t, const Args&... args) {
                getSizeImpl<T>(first, t, std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<T, size_t>::value>());
                return getSize(t, args...);
            }
        template<typename T>
            void getSizeImpl(const char* first, const T& t, std::false_type) {
                // Case when the next argument is not a size_t type
                size += strlen(first);
            }
        template<typename T>
            void getSizeImpl(const char* first,const T& t, std::true_type) {
                // Do nothing
            }
        template<typename... Args>
            int getSize(size_t s, const Args&... args) {
                size += s;
                std::cout << "size_t " << s << " in getSize" << std::endl;
                return getSize(args...);
            }
        void join() {
            std::cout << "Final capacity : " << ret.capacity() << std::endl;
        }
        template<typename... Args>
            void join(const std::string& first, Args&&... args) {
                ret.append(first);
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        template<typename... Args>
            void join(char* first, Args&&... args) {
                ret.append(first);
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        template<typename... Args>
            void join(const char* first, Args&&... args) {
                ret.append(first);
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        template<typename... Args>
            void join(size_t s, Args&&... args) {
                join(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
};
```

main :

```
int main() {
    std::string s1 = "hello";
    std::string s2 = "world !";
    std::string s3 = "meatpopsicle";
    const char* s4 = "__yeah__";
    joinStr c(s1, s2, s3, s4, (size_t)8);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You are reusing moved-from values in `joinStr::joinStr` if any of the arguments are rvalues. You shouldn't forward into `getSize`. Also string literals are `const char *`, so they will be forced into the `const std::string&` overload

Comment: yeah you're right. I'll update the code with your suggestion.

Comment: @Clonk: Looks nice. Is there a way to pass a `const char* s, int n` if the string is not null terminated?

Comment: @Clonk: With some cleaning, you may do [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54f6fdb65f11b33b)

Comment: @Jarod42 That is a cleaner and very elegant way to do the first case ! Out of curiosity, how would you implement the possibility of giving a size_t argument after a char* without resorting to recursive functions ?

Comment: I would take a `std::pair<const char*, std::size_t>` or similar structure.